# Using DropDownListFor jquery does not get the currently selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added an onchange event to the DropDownlistFor which is working fine, I think.

I am adding a new dropdownlistfor into the DOM so that I can have multiple selected items *(note the multiple dropdowns contain different data sources)*.

When the dropdowns are created, the id's are all different, but work along the lines of

```
newObject_XX__dropDownName
```

Where XX is an incremental number starting at 0, and are added to the DOM using the following:

```
$(XX).change(function(){ FunkyTest(this); });
```

Where XX is newObject_XX__dropDownName from above.

And the javascript function FunckyTest is as follows.

```
function FunkyTest(event)
{
    var e = event.id;
    var elem = "select#" + e + " option.selected"
    var t = $(elem).text();
    var v = $(elem).val();
    alert(q); 
}
```

I am trying to get the currently selected data from the dropdown.

```
$("select#newObject_XX__dropDownName option:selected").text();
```

This is the method shown by the jQuery website, but when I replace the "select#newObject_XX__dropDownName option:selected" for the var elem within FunkyTest it does not work.

Comment: Can you try to do this  var elem = "select#" + e + " option:selected"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry all.

Found solution.....

```
var t = $("select#" + event.id + " option:selected").text()
var v = $("select#" + event.id + " option:selected").val()
```

Does the job.